# Disposing JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose

How can I dispose `JFrame` from another class? My code is listed below.

```
public class MainWindow

{

JFrame main_f = new JFrame("xx");
main_f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
main_f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
.
.
.
}
```

Disposing class:

```
public static void DisposingJFrame (){
.
.
.
MainWindow.main_f.dispose();
}
```

`MainWindow.main_f.dispose()` won't work because `main_f` isn't a variable. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggestion**:

Make the `JFrame` instance a *field* of the `MainWindow` class, and provide an *accessor* method for it.

```
public final class MainWindow{
    private final JFrame main_f;

    public MainWindow(){
        main_f = new JFrame("xx");
        main_f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main_f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        .
        .
        .
    }

    public final JFrame getMainFrame(){
        return main_f;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And then in the `Disposing` class, you should have a `MainWindow` instance, where you'll simply do the following to dispose of its `JFrame` instance:

```
mainWindowInstance.getMainFrame().dispose();
```

**Recommendation**:

- Read the [Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) tutorial. This is basic OOP.

---

**Edit**:

This is to address the errors that you're seeing:

1. variable main_f might not have been initialized
2. cannot find symbol "mainWindowInstance"

With regard to the first error, this is because in the example I provided, I used the `final` modifier. This field must be initialized upon object creation. Therefore, you must have more than one constructor. To resolve this, either remove the `final` modifier, or initialize the `main_f` field in every constructor of `MainWindow`.

With regard to the second error, `mainWindowInstance` is something that I left for ***you*** to create. Here's a "for instance" -

```
public class Disposing{
    private MainWindow mainWindowInstance;

    public Disposing(){
        mainWindowInstance = new MainWindow();
        .
        .
        .
    }

    public void diposeMainFrame(){
        mainWindowInstance.getMainFrame().dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Makaroni, Also, if you made `main_f` a `static` field, this would work the way you're trying to dispose of it, but that's not really OOP.

Comment: IDE gives me 2 errors now: 1st. "variable main_f might not have been initialized", and 2nd: cannot find symbol "mainWindowInstance". Should I import something?

Comment: @Makaroni, What errors? Can you include your updated code? Please provide this information as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make main_f to be a static variable if you want to access it like this.

BUT, this is non object pattern. Instead of that,  do this :

- make your MainWindow to be a singleton
- make your main_f a field of your MainWindow
- call MainWindow.getInstance().getFrame().dispose()

Another way is to give to DisposingJFrame the instance of MainWindow (like that, you don't need to declare MainFrame as a singleton)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simplest way of doing this. The Java code for disposing the JFrame of a class from another class is as follows:

```
public class Main extends JFrame
{
  Main()
  {
    Main x=new Main();
    Other.a=x;
  }
}

public class Other extends JFrame
{
   static Main a;

   Other()
   {  
      a.dispose();
    }
}
```