# Dispose a JFrame on button click from another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose

As many probably know, I am a complete Java newbie. I have already attempted to research this (by reading other posts on StackOverflow, Googling and asking a friend who is less of a java newbie) but I can't figure it out. The answer is probably clear and easy but I am blind to it. I am attempting to dispose a `JFrame` from a different frame.

My application is supposed to work as follows:

- Frame X has a button, when pressed: spawns frame Y
- Frame Y has a button, when pressed: spawns frame Z
- Frame Z has a button, when pressed: performs method from frame Y before disposing frame Y and itself.

Getting frame Z to dispose frame Y is where most of my issues are.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Ideally help will be phrased in such a way that even a baby could understand (because that is my level of Java comprehension).

I know many will think this is a duplicate question of either [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122349/disposing-jframe-from-another-class) or [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966935/dispose-jframe-from-another-class). I believe it is not a duplicate question because I have read both and have not understood how to resolve my own problem.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Whilst I can appreciate that using multiple JFrames is a bad practice, I already use multiple JFrames and don't know how to do it any other way yet.

Comment: *"..don't know how to do it any other way yet."*  The accepted answer to that question showed a dozen ways..  The best solution depends on what these frames do, what they contain.

Comment: Consider using a `CardLayout` ([How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Frame Z has a button, when pressed: performs method from frame Y before disposing frame Y and itself.

Frame Y and frame Z should be modal dialogs (at least Z should be, probably also Y).

When dialog Y goes to open dialog Z (we'll call it `dialogZ`) the code should go something like this:

```
DialogZ dialogZ = new DialogZ(..);
dialogZ.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false); // at this point, dialogZ will have been closed
```

See [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) for details and example code.

> (Frame Z) … **performs method** from frame Y

Frame Y and Frame Z should probably ***not*** extend any class.  Instead they should be instance variables that are used as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could hold a reference to the other jframe in another frame. this class could look like this:

The constructor takes a jframe, which should be controlled from this jframe.

```
class YourFrame {
   public YourFrame(JFrame controlFrame){
       //build the frame and a button, which action listener calls controlFrame.setVisible(false);
       JFrame f = new JFrame();
       f.setSize(800, 600);
       JPanel content = new JPanel();
       JButton button = new JButton();
       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               controlFrame.setVisible(false);
            }
       }
       content.add(button); 
       f.add(content);
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```